# SVN merge - how to prevent code deletion/overwrite errors

Tags: svn, version-control

During code merge process, we faced the issue of code being overwritten or even deleted, so we are asking for suggestions.

- We are a team of six developers in two different offices using Tortoise SVN.
- We have 12 personal branches, 2 for each developer: `dev1Client`, `dev1Server`,..., `dev6Client`, `dev6Sever`.
- We have shared branches `QA_Client`, `QA_Server`, `Release_Client`, `Release_Server`.

Steps we follow:

1. All developers commit work to their branches, and then they merge their changes to `QA_Client` and `QA_Server`.
2. QA Build is prepared from `QA_Client` and `QA_Server`.
3. Once it passes tests, admin creates a tag with release number and merges the code to `Release_Client` and `Release_Server`.

A couple of times is step 1 code was overwritten or deleted during the merge process. The main reason we have found that developers are not syncing their branches with the QA_Branches.

For example, Dev1 & Dev4 have merged code to `QA*` branches and the rest of the developers have not synced their branches with the `QA*`. After that Dev2 may try to merge his code to `QA*` get some conflict warnings. He interprets those warnings incorrectly and overwrites some of the earlier changes made by Dev1 and Dev4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pointed out the root cause yourself:

> The main reason we have found that developers are not syncing their branches with the QA_Branches.

Your team should have a strict policy of always bringing the personal `dev*` branches up to date with the latest changes in `QA*` branches before developers merge their new code into `QA*`. The developers also need to understand what different merge conflict messages mean and how to solve them, [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html) is an excellent reference.

In short, you cannot replace personal responsibility (or a lack of thereof) with tools. The policy can be enforced by making the guilty developer retroactively fix the broken merge ;)

Comment: In SVN all developers will have to up to date their branches with the latest changes in QA* branches else these kinds of problems will keep on happening. 
Do you know any other Version Control system like TFS or GitHub or any other where these kinds of issues will not occur?

Comment: @David I think you can have these problems in any version control system, but distributed ones (like Git or Mercurial) probably make it easier to avoid them by allowing to first pull changes from remote repository to a local copy of the shared branch, do necessary merges and push changes back to remote branch only after that.